# What is a realistic launch speed of a grappling hook gun?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, order-of-magnitude

In The Dark Knight, at the end of the movie Batman throws the Joker off of a building and then shoots his grapple hook gun to catch him. Is 68m/s a reasonable speed for a grapple gun to shoot?

Comment: What do You mean by "reasonable"? Whether it is possible?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this one http://skeptics.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](http://www.resqmax.com/tresqmax.php) to such a device that one can purchase.

The manufacturer claims

> The Tactical ResQmax™ is capable of deploying a standard line up to 250 feet / 75 meters with the standard projectile depending on the service pressure, weight of line and type of projectile used. Distances of over 400 feet / 120 meters can be achieved using customized line options.

Let's consider the "customized line options" statement of 120 meters.

Additionally, let's treat the projectile as a point object, take air resistance to be negligible, and ignore the effects of the non-massless line. I believe doing so will cause an *underestimate* of the actual launch speed. Oh well. Order of magnitude blah blah.

Let's also take the reasonable assumption that the manufacturers/marketing team chose those numbers to represent the distance the projectile travels when launched from a level surface at 45 degrees.

With these assumptions, we can use a [well-known equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile) in kinematics: 
$$d=\frac{v^2\sin(2\theta)}{g},$$
where each of the quantities represents what one might suspect. Plugging in values for $d$, $g$, and $\theta$, I find
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{dg}{\sin(2\theta)}}=\sqrt{\frac{120\cdot 9.81}{1}}\ \mathrm{m/s}=34\ \mathrm{m/s}.$$

Remember this is an underestimate, though I doubt it's off by too much.

So is 68 meters per second reasonable? No idea.